# Best method for submitting multiple options with associated values

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a project in which I'm going to have a long list of items with an associated value or two that I want a user to be able to click on and add to a database.

For example I'd like a page with these values:

```
Cat, animal_id=1
Dog, animal_id=2
Pig, animal_id=3
etc.
```

Now if this was only a few items I'd use multiple forms:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" name="animal_form1" id="animal_form1">
   <input id="animal_name" name="animal_name" type="hidden" value="cat" />
   <input id="animal_id" name="animal_id" type="hidden" value="1" />
   <input type="submit" name="animal_add" id="animal_add" value="add" />
</form>

<form action="add.php" method="post" name="animal_form2" id="animal_form2">
   <input id="animal_name" name="animal_name" type="hidden" value="cat" />
   <input id="animal_id" name="animal_id" type="hidden" value="1" />
   <input type="submit" name="animal_add" id="animal_add" value="add" />
</form>

etc.
```

but if there are a whole lot of items with many associated values I want to submit, what would be the most effective way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a select box that includes all needed values at once:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" name="animal_form" id="animal_form">
    <select name="animal">
        <option value="cat|1" />Cat 1</option>
        <option value="cat|2" />Cat 2</option>
        <option value="pig|3" />Pig 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="animal_add" id="animal_add" value="add" />
</form>
```

and in php, split it:

```
$animal = explode('|', $_POST['animal']);
echo $animal[0] . ', animal_id=' . $animal[1];
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there not a more elegant solution? I should've mentioned, but I was hoping to use ajax too